# how to mock different responses for a method with different parameters in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock my external service and my method that dealing with the external service look like:

```
public class ExternalConnector{
    public ResponseRaw callExternal(RequestParams request, ResponseRaw responseType){
    ...my implementation to call external service...
    }
}
```

and I mock my response as follow:

```
ExternalConnector externalConnector = Mockito.spy(new ExternalConnector());

ResonseRaw myMockResponse = ..... mock the response
RequestParams myParameter = ..... mock the params

doReturn(myMockResponse)//
    .when(externalConnector)//
    .callExternal(isA(myParameter.getClass()), isA(MyResponse.class));
```

Till now it worked fine. But if I make another mock for my callExternal method with another RequestParams object, then it will get confused here and does not know which response it should mock, something like :

```
ResonseRaw myMockResponse = ..... mock the response
RequestParams myParameter = ..... mock the params

doReturn(myMockResponse)//
    .when(externalConnector)//
    .callExternal(isA(myParameter.getClass()), isA(MyResponse.class));

ResonseRaw myMockResponse2 = ..... mock the response
RequestParams myParameter2 = ..... mock the params

doReturn(myMockResponse2)//
    .when(externalConnector)//
    .callExternal(isA(myParameter2.getClass()), isA(MyResponse.class));
```

The problem is that myParameter.getClass() and myParameter2.getClass() both return the same RequestParams class type, and therefore basically the signiture for the mock is the same for both cases.

I tried to change the signiture for my mock from isA to eq, but it still did not work:

```
doReturn(myMockResponse2)//
    .when(externalConnector)//
    .callExternal(eq(myParameter), isA(MyResponse.class));
```

Can anyone help me at this point here? Thank you

Comment: the second is overriding the first. you can either put some logic in an argument catcher or as you tried before use the `eq` for the intended parameters.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, thank you for your hint. Can you please give me more details about the solution or an example would be very appriciate. Thank you.